# how to use fnFilter with scroll datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

i have datatable and i used multi search in it , this code below

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
var dataTable = $('table').dataTable();
  

var input = $(".dataTables_filter input");
input.unbind('keyup search input').bind('keypress', function (e) {
if (e.which == 13) {
   var keywords = input.val().split(','), filter ='';
   for (var i=0; i<keywords.length; i++) {
       filter = (filter!=='') ? filter+'|'+keywords[i] : keywords[i];
   }            
   dataTable.fnFilter(filter, null, true, false, true, true);
}
});
});
```

and when data is to large it goes messy ,
i tried to use below with prev code

```
$('table').dataTable({"scrollX":true;});
```

and here's my table tag

```
<table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; width: 100%;">
```

i need here to make my table scroll x or the paragraph in td tag shows all without any miss,

thanks

Comment: I'm confused about your last sentence. Do you think you can explain a bit more what is your expected result, please?

Comment: A snippet would help

Comment: i am sorry about my language , i meant i need to use scroll x with fnFilter , thanks.